# Integral involving $e^{cos\theta}$, $e^x$ Chebyshev series expansion

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate the coefficients of the Chebyshev series expansion of $f(x)=e^x$.

To that end, one has to calculate the definite integral:

$a_n=\int_{-1}^1\frac{T_n(x)e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

where $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) satisfying $T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos n\theta$.

Naturally, the change of variable $x=\cos\theta$ is required here, which reforms the integral into:

$a_n=\int_{-\pi}^0 e^{\cos\theta}\cos n\theta d\theta$

Any ideas on how to calculate this last integral?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#i

Comment: So it is actually the modified bessel Function at $1$so $a_n=I_n(1)= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!\ (m+n)! }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2m+n}$

Comment: Yeap, it seems that this would be it. I'm going to calculate some coefficients and come back. Thank you all guys

Comment: Continuing the discussion, is there any nice way to compute $I_n(x)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ at $x=1$, or do i just have to truncate the above sum up to the number of terms i deem accurate enough?

Comment: I would have write ${{2m+n}\choose{m}} \dfrac{1}{(2m+n)! \times 4^{2m} } $